# How can you pass parameters to kivy button's bind functions

Tags: python, function, button, kivy

Actuall i was trying to add a parameter to my kivy button's bind method which is like `def on_release_func(self,instance,something)` where something refers to any parameter.Now in button's bind function `MDRectangleFlatButton.bind(on_release = self.on_release_func(my_parameter))` is giving me error that `on_release_func() missing one required positional argument 'something'`. I tried using lambda function but when I am clicking the Button it is again giving error `lambda takes zero positional argument but one was given` .. I used lambda like `MDRectangleFlatButton.bind(on_release = lambda : self.on_release_func(my_parameter))`

Any idea how can I resolve my issue

example code

```
class Myapplin(MDApp):

    def any_function(self):
        self.card_imgs_box = BoxLayout()
        self.img_disp_btn = MDFillRoundFlatButton(text='Img 1')

        id_btn = int(self.img_disp_btn.text[-1]) - 1

        self.img_disp_btn.bind(on_release=lambda: self.display_btn_img(id_btn))
        self.card_imgs_box.add_widget(self.img_disp_btn)


    def display_btn_img(self,instance,id):
        return id*id
    def build(self):
        return something()

Myapplin().run()
```

Here the function are in MDApp class. this function any_function is used by some other widget in something class

Answer (score 2):

The function you pass to `on_release` will have the instance being released passed as its first (and only explicit) argument.

Therefore if you have a function declared as `def on_release_func(self,instance,something)` as you describe, you should bind it as `.bind(on_release=lambda instance: self.on_release_func(instance, your_parameter))`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply brother it worked as charm